# How to check Grails session isinvalidated in gsp

Tags: session, grails, gsp, invalidation

I am trying to implement login homepage with the following code:

```
             <g:if test="${session != null}">
                <li><span style='padding:7px;color:#15c'>${session.name}</span></li>
                <li> <a href="${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'doLogout')}">Sign out</a> </li> 
              </g:if>
              <g:else>
                <li> <a href="${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'login')}">Login</a> </li>
                <li ><a href="${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'register')}">Sign Up</a></li>
              </g:else>
```

but it is not working, any help? thanks.

Comment: What is the exact problem? If there is an error message, could you post it here? If not, what are your current thoughts?

Comment: One thing comes to mind, you always have a session so your first check will never be true.  What you'd want to check is something like session.user != null where when you do a successful login, you set that variable.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to put the error. Here you go: 
Error 500: Internal Server Error
getAttribute: Session already invalidated

Comment: what i am trying to do is to check is the current session is invalidated or not. I tried the session.user != null, still get the same error.